# Sobre los contenedores en Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap

Soy nuevo en Bootstrap 4. Me he leído la documentación y pensaba que todo en Bootstrap tiene que tener un contenedor, y dentro de este filas donde poder meter el sistema de columnas.

Pero luego me encuentro con elementos como los Nav y veo que no necesitan tener un contenedor.

Cuando sería necesario meter un contenedor, y cuando no? Que filosofía debemos seguir a la hora de distribuir nuestros elementos, especialmente cuando son de ancho fijo y no queremos que se expandan?

Tengo mucho lío con la distribución de los elementos en el diseño, luego cada componente ya lo entiendo.

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

cuando hablas de "contenedor" es un termino bastante amplio, personalmente no sé si te refieres al contenedor del mismo elemento o del que está contenido.

Contenedor del mismo elemento:
Por ejemplo, si le das a F12 y seleccionas estos párrafos, verás que mis palabras están "contenidas" por un `<p>` todos las etiquetas contienen algo, por ejemplo:

```
<section> <div> <p> hola </p> </div> </section>
```

Aunque también es cierto que puedes crear `<i></i>`

Por ejemplo a ese hola que está contenido en el p, puedes darle las propiedades que quieras, como ancho,alto,tipo fuente etc...

Contenedores:
Todo se trata como si fuese unas estructuras de cajas, que se van poniendo una al lado de la otras, a excepción de algunas etiquetas que por si mismas tienen display:block, que se colocaran debajo, independiente de que su caja anterior, no haya ocupado el 100% de la pantalla...
Para colocar estos contenedores, tendrás que usar los class="row" y dentro los col-algo y hacer la estructura que mejor te venga a ti, o te hayan pedido.
Por eso mismo la filosofía... de como lo distribuyas es cosa tuya "cuanto de ancho tiene que ocupar, etc ".

Si es verdad que con html5, "podemos dividir" el contenido para que un desarrollador sea más legible de leer.
Por ejemplo imagínate un periódico: tiene la sección de futbol,la de música..etc y dentro de cada una pues más cosas...

```
<section class="futbol">
  <article="seccionEspañola">
  <div> </div>
  </article>
 <article="seccionFrancesa">
  <div> </div>
  </article>
</section>
```